# Sublime Text 2 - RubyTest with ruby 2.0 not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sublimetext2, ruby-2.0, ruby-test

I am trying to set up my ST2 to be able to run my tests from the editor.  When I hit 'Command' +'Shift'+'T' I keep getting some kind of runtime error.  Here is the stack trace.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
No DRb server is running. Running in local process instead ...
/Users/susiehamm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/bundler-1.3.0.pre.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:31:in `block in setup': You have already activated rspec-core 2.13.0, but your Gemfile requires rspec-core 2.11.1. Using bundle exec may solve this. (Gem::LoadError)
    from /Users/susiehamm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/bundler-1.3.0.pre.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:17:in `setup'
    from /Users/susiehamm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/bundler-1.3.0.pre.2/lib/bundler.rb:117:in `setup'
    from /Users/susiehamm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/bundler-1.3.0.pre.2/lib/bundler/setup.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/susiehamm/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:110:in `require'
    from /Users/susiehamm/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:110:in `rescue in require'
    from /Users/susiehamm/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:35:in `require'
    from /Users/susiehamm/Documents/Rails/sample_app/config/boot.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/susiehamm/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
    from /Users/susiehamm/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
    from /Users/susiehamm/Documents/Rails/sample_app/config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/susiehamm/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
    from /Users/susiehamm/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
    from /Users/susiehamm/Documents/Rails/sample_app/config/environment.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/susiehamm/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
    from /Users/susiehamm/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
    from /Users/susiehamm/Documents/Rails/sample_app/spec/spec_helper.rb:10:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/susiehamm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/spork-0.9.2/lib/spork.rb:24:in `prefork'
    from /Users/susiehamm/Documents/Rails/sample_app/spec/spec_helper.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/susiehamm/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
    from /Users/susiehamm/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
    from /Users/susiehamm/Documents/Rails/sample_app/spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/susiehamm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:819:in `load'
    from /Users/susiehamm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:819:in `block in load_spec_files'
    from /Users/susiehamm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:819:in `each'
    from /Users/susiehamm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:819:in `load_spec_files'
    from /Users/susiehamm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.0/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:22:in `run'
    from /Users/susiehamm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:77:in `rescue in run'
    from /Users/susiehamm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:73:in `run'
    from /Users/susiehamm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:17:in `block in autorun'
[Finished in 0.8s with exit code 1]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error seems pretty explanatory:

> You have already activated rspec-core 2.13.0, but your Gemfile requires rspec-core 2.11.1. Using bundle exec may solve this. (Gem::LoadError)

Either adjust the version of your rspec-rails (containing rspec-core) or run with bundle exec.

Solution:

Within your gemfile, change:

```
gem 'rspec-rails', '2.11.0'
```

To:

```
gem 'rspec rails', '2.13.0'
```

Comment: I had tried that earlier.  I get `bundler: command not found: rspec-core`.

Comment: Does it respond to bundle exec rspec-rails install (if you have rspec-rails gem)? Or more generally, bundle exec gem install rspec?

Comment: I have `gem 'rspec-rails', '2.11.0'` in my Gemfile.  There are no errors when I run `bundle install`.  I assume rspec-core is a dependency of this rspec-rails gem, so how would I specify the specific rspec-core that I want.  I did run the gem install like you said and it installed rpsec-2.13.0 gem.  This did not fix my problem.

Comment: Did you run it with bundle exec in front of it? And can you check the version of your rspec-core in your gemfile.lock?

Comment: I have 2 listed.  `rspec (2.11.0)
      rspec-core (~> 2.11.0)
      rspec-expectations (~> 2.11.0)
      rspec-mocks (~> 2.11.0)
    rspec-core (2.11.1)`.  This is the version that the error says it is looking for.

Comment: How about changing gem 'rspec-rails', '2.11.0' to gem 'rspec rails', '2.13.0'?